# Getting data value from ALMemory using JS

Tags: javascript, python, nao-robot, pepper

When I try to get data from `ALMemory` with the following code:

```
session.service("ALMemory").done(function (ALMemory) {
    var value = ALMemory.getData("ALTextToSpeech/TextDone");
});
```

This `value` is of type `AL::ALValue`. How can I cast it to int, because in this case it is expected to be 0 for currently speaking and 1 for currently not speaking. I have tried to cast it to int or to number or to string with different methods, but with no success.

When I am using this functionality with python SDK:

```
def onLoad(self):
    self.memory = ALProxy("ALMemory")

def onUnload(self):
    self.memory = None

def onInput_checkIfSpeaking(self, p):
    value = self.memory.getData("ALTextToSpeech/TextDone")
```

this `value` is of type int, not `AL::ALValue`. Is that possible to be achieved with JavaScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set your value in a callback (all functions return promises, on which you can attach callbacks: `promise.then(onFulfilled, onRejected)`):

```
session.service("ALMemory").then( function (ALMemory) {
    ALMemory.getData("ALTextToSpeech/TextDone").then( function (TextDone) {
         var value = TextDone;
    });
});
```

For the record, the documentation is here: http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/dev/js/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Did you try a standard java:

```
value = (int)(self.memory.getData("ALTextToSpeech/TextDone"))
```

?

Comment: I need it for js, not for python

Comment: Yeah sorry, I read "java" instead of js. In JS did you try Number() or ParseInt() ?

Comment: The result this method returns is always an empty object `{}`, not 0 or 1 as it is expected.

Comment: Are you on a real robot ?

Comment: Just to be sure, could you connect to your nao shell (putty or ssh) and launch this type of command: qicli call ALMemory.getData ALTextToSpeech/TextDone

Comment: This works, it prints 0, which is the expected value when Pepper is not talking.

Comment: So sorry, I have no idea

Comment: I got why I had problems - I have not used promise when calling the `ALMemory.getData("ALTextToSpeech/TextDone")`. It should look like `ALMemory.getData("ALTextToSpeech/TextDone").then( function...)`